# Highlight matched letters/words in a search list using ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I looked through different sources having similar question, and I got this so far:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
  render(results,values) {
   var regex = new RegExp("(" + values + ")", "gi");
   var name = this.props.name;
   return (
       <div style={myCssStyle}>{name.replace(regex, "<em>$1</em>")}</div>
  );
 });
});
```

so now if I search for "la" in the list and considering there are multiple matches to it one among them being: "last", it outputs:

```
<em>la</em>st
```

how can i display name with bold or italic and not have the "`<em>`" in the lits.

UPDATE::::::

I updated my code as per ScottWe's suggestion and it works for cases where there are no repeated letters found eg: when i search for "o", it gives:

[image]

[image]

the words are : **color** and **onRowClick**

Expected o/p:

c**o**lor  ->searching for 'o' in the list

**c**lick ->searching for 'c' in the list

I dont necessarily have to highlight the  other 'o' or 'c' in the above words.?

hope this helps!!!

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this,

```
var regex = new RegExp("(" + values + ")", "gi");
var match = name.match(regex)

if (match != null) {
    var parts = name.split(match[0], 2)

    return (
        <div style={myCssStyle}>{parts[0]}<em>{match[0]}</em>{parts[1]} />
    );
}
else {
    return (
        <div style={myCssStyle}>{name}</div>
    );
}
```

First, this will find all matches in the string as an array. When a regex match fails, it will return null. If the variable's not null, you will know there's at least one match, and that the first index of the array is the first match. From there you can split the string, and build the display you want. Otherwise, it will just print the div with the original name. I hope that works.

Comment: ScottWe: with the above approach  its rendering the same thing, now with the <span> element instead of <em>..Well the question is there a way to convert the string and parse it so that it does not render as plain text

Comment: this is what i tried: '<div style={propertyName}>{name.replace(regex, "<span className='search-match'>$1</span>")}</div>'

Comment: @user1234 Sorry about the last part. I didn't think name was a styling object, since it's also the list you're styling. I know what the style attribute does, so I just wanted to make sure that wasn't a mistake. As for the main question, I feel kind of lost at what you're asking. First, is name a string or an object? If you're using it for inline styling, but also parsing as a string, it must be both...? Secondly, what do you want as opposed to plain text? Finally, what is the desired output format? I feel like there's not enough information to really answer the question in its current state.

Comment: @user1234 I believe I understand the question now. I wrongly assumed that it was able to parse the <em> so I didn't bother testing it. I updated the solution to what I believe should work. I did a quick test. Let me know if that solves it.

Comment: ScottWe: thanks for your help, it works for most cases, but fails for repeated words. I've updated the Ques above. not sure how to get only the first matched element and ignore the rest..Thanks again in advance!!

Comment: My apologies. I thought you just wanted to highlight the first match. I'll try to update this soon, unless someone else answers it first.

Comment: ScottWe: ohh my apologies too..I realized it only after testing it..I still would like to highlight the first matched letter in the word as your code does, only that it chops off the remaining letters after a second match is found(eg:click: it displays only "cli" and chops anything after second 'c' found in the word..thanks!

Comment: ScottWe: tried this:  var parts = name.split(match[0], 3) and then in return stmt:  return (
        <div style={myCssStyle}>{parts[0]}<em>{match[0]}</em>{parts[1]}{parts[2]} />
    ); but it fails when there are more than 2 matching letters in the same word...eg: disabledDoubled